# FFMPEG generates an empty master playlist

Tags: php, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I use the following FFMPEG command to generate playlists and a master-playlist for later insertion into a player with HLS support:

```
ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe -i input/test.mp4 
-preset fast  
-g 150 
-sc_threshold 0 
-threads 4 
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 
-filter:v:0 scale=h=240:w=-2  -minrate:v:0 75k  -maxrate:v:0 218k  -bufsize:v:0 300k -b:v:0 150k  
-filter:v:1 scale=h=360:w=-2  -minrate:v:1 138k -maxrate:v:1 400k -bufsize:v:1 552k -b:v:1 276k 
-filter:v:2 scale=h=480:w=-2 -minrate:v:2 375k -maxrate:v:2 1088k -bufsize:v:2 1500k -b:v:2 750k 
-filter:v:3 scale=h=720:w=-2  -minrate:v:3 512k -maxrate:v:3 1485k -bufsize:v:3 2048k -b:v:3 1024k 
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3" 
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 
-f hls -hls_time 6 -segment_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_format mpegts 
-hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_filename "output/conversion/K8eYn1X1/res-%v/segment-%d.ts"  output/conversion/K8eYn1X1/res-%v/playlist.m3u8
```

Based on information from various sources, this command line should do the following:

1. take a video stream from the input file,
2. apply filters with different settings four times,
3. combine it into one stream,
4. cut into TS-fragments for 6 seconds,
5. write information about each resolution to the playlist.m3u8,
6. create a master-playlist and write information about upcoming playlists in it

Everything works correctly, BUT: fragments are created, playlists are created, but the master file is empty

If you play with the command line, more precisely, leave only one filter, then everything works fine: and fragments are cut and playlists are created and a master-playlist is also created

Also, I noticed that if I watched the folder in which all the files are stored, I noticed one thing: when using the command given above, a 7kb file is created, and then in the same second, it seems to be cleared . Why is this happening, I do not understand

Upon completion of processing in the log, the last line:

```
[hls @ 000001ff73b87200] Opening 'output/conversion/K8eYn1X1/master.m3u8' for writing
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Maybe the commands are in the wrong order? Tell me, who knows?

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce here. I get master pls listing the 4 variant pls. Share full log.

Comment: https://codepen.io/barahten/pen/xxxqWPx

Comment: The log looks to be missing the final lines. Upgrade to latest ffmpeg and check.

Comment: It was experimentally possible to establish that the case in the parameter -hls_playlist_type vod.  EVENT does not fit, I had to delete this parameter. Yes, everything worked fine, but the file no longer matches Apple’s recommendations.
I saw somewhere out of the corner of my eye that this is a bug of FFMPEG itself and there are already patches, but, unfortunately, I can’t find the link anymore ((